# How to add multiple values in a single column in Angular Material?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Currently each column contains a single value from a single property of JSON. I want to concatenate several of these property values in a single column in an Angular Material Table. How should I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom field called `name` in the TS file , where name is the combination of `firstName` and `lastName`.

Then specify `{{element.firstName}} {{element.lastName}}` in the HTML file.

Example:

In TS file:

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['name'];
```

In HTML file:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.firstName}}{{element.lastName}}</td>
  </ng-container>
  
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  
 </table>
```

Comment: how do you combine the properties into a custom field?

Comment: In TS file specify a custom name , then specify that name in HTML under    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">     and then under  ng-container tag add  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.firstName}} }{{element.lastName}} </td> . This would do the trick.

Comment: Oh I mean in the TS file, so I just declare a name variable?